# Certificate validation failed for TensorFlow hub, Elmo module

Tags: urlopen, elmo

I am trying to import the Elmo module using the url:

```
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3", trainable=True)
```

but am unable to load it as it is giving an error:

> URLError: urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1076)

can anyone help me to get this thing work?

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error